# Is it okay to reuse disposable bottle nipples?

Tags: feeding, bottle-feeding

We were sent home from the hospital with some small botttles and (regular sized?) nipple tops that came individually wrapped in sterile packaging that says "use once".

We got a few bottles at the shower but all are wide mouth and way too large for our new born.

Is it okay to reuse these nipples by washing them and throw these nipples in a pot of boiling water with the bottles?  Is there a reason I should not do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the "use once" warning was meant as instruction for the hospital staff. Cleaning and sanitizing them properly should be fine, or at the very least no worse than doing the same for the store bought ones. 
 Congrats on your little one! :)

Answer (score 1):

(we sanitized and reused some when we were in a bind....shhhh don't tell)

***Disclaimer***: I am not a health professional so take this as being based purely on anecdotal discovery.

Sanitizing and reusing is ok, but after 1 or 2 sanitizing runs they start to warp as the plastic is cheaply made and meant to be disposable, so I wouldn't recommend using the same one more than a couple times.

Good news is you can buy large packs of those nipples on Amazon for fairly cheap.